# Implementation details of semantic web services

Tags: web-services, wsdl, owl, semantic-web

The intention is to build a intra-network semantic web services, but struggling to get the concepts together. Please care to answer the following questions:

- We annotate ontologies to WSDL elements in [SAWSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sawsdl/), but where does the web server store the reference ontology file for the benefit of client?
- Is it mandatory to describe the pre-conditions and effects of atomic/simple processes? If yes, why?
- As per W3C specifications, unlike SAWSDL, [OWL-S](https://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/) decouples the ontology and WSDL files. WSDL, which is completely decoupled from semantics, is used only at the time of service invocation. If that is the case, how does client find ontology information during service discovery phase?

Comment: Nobody has any views on this?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/kmi/msm4j will be a good start

Answer (score 1):

In SAWSDL, concepts are identified by URIs in the form of attribute values of the modelReference attribute.